# MudTextBox OnFocus or OnClick text should be cleared

Tags: mudblazor

Good Day Every one,

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value=@Data[item.Key]
Immediate="true"
OnBlur="@(e=>addCartItem(item.Key, item.Value))"
Margin="Margin.Dense"
Variant="Variant.Outlined"
AdornmentText="€"
Adornment="Adornment.End">
```

Initially this TextField is bind with 0 value. I want when this TextField is focused or user click on it to enter some value, this 0 value should be removed leaving the TextField blank. Please guid me how can this be done.
Thanks

Comment: Are you accepting numbers or string into the field? How do you get the 0 value? Do you assign the value to 0 by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably binding to a non-nullable numeric variable. You should bind to a nullable variable so that the default value is null and the text field is empty.

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="TextValue" Label="Filled" Variant="Variant.Filled"></MudTextField>

@code {
    public int? TextValue { get; set; }
}
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEccPOkHGFWLYbJx